# Is it possible to yield a playwright object in a fixture for reuse?

Tags: python, pytest, playwright-python

I am learning how to use pytest and keep running into an issue with fixtures.

Below is the source from the test file:

```python3
import asyncio, pytest
from SingletonObject import SObject
from playwright.async_api import expect, async_playwright

@pytest.fixture
async def playwright_instance():
    async with async_playwright() as playwright:
        yield playwright

async def test_for_SObject_connectivity():
    async with async_playwright() as playwright_instance:
        # Create a single instance of SObject with the playwright instance passed in
        test = SObject(playwright_instance) 
        # Opens up a new tab and navigates it to a defined url
        await test.start() 
        # Ensures that the page is actually loaded to the defined url
        await expect(test.search_page).to_have_url("[specific url]")
```

I am trying to have the SObject represent a "website as a module" to perform searches and download files, so I need to pass in the playwright object specifically for testing.

The issue I keep having is pytest doesn't end up returning the playwright instance, instead it just passes the function signature itself which causes a error in SObject since it is trying to grab a variable from the playwright object. Based on the [pytest fixtures documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/fixtures.html) it should "just work," but I'm not that lucky.

Doing it like this:

```python3
async def test_for_SObject_connectivity():
    async with async_playwright() as playwright_instance:
        test = SObject(playwright_instance)
        ...
```

does work, but I wanted to see if a fixture could be used instead.

I know that Playwright has a pytest plugin that lets me pass in a playwright object ([Testing Playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/writing-tests)) but when I try to run the test method with it Playright passed in the test fails with `RunetimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loops is running`. If I try to run pytest without using the pytest-asyncio plugin it complains that I'm trying to run tests without the plugin.

Could it be an issue with running inside a with statement? Or running asynchronously?

Comment: Please don't edit to put answers in the question. Putting an answer in the answers section, upvoting, and/or accepting the answer (check mark) is the way to indicate your question was answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you passing in the fixture to your test? Based on your function signature comment, I suspect not. You need to explicitly pass it in unless `autouse=True` is set on the fixture.

Try this:

```
async def test_for_SObject_connectivity(playwright_instance):
    test = SObject(playwright_instance) 
    # Opens up a new tab and navigates it to a defined url
    await test.start() 
    # Ensures that the page is actually loaded to the defined url
    await expect(test.search_page).to_have_url("[specific url]")
```

Comment: Hours of staring at this to just be a simple mistake... wonderful... thanks for the help.

Edit: Rereading the docs for pytest it implies it but i skimmed over it
"In this example, test_fruit_salad “requests” fruit_bowl (i.e. def test_fruit_salad(fruit_bowl):), and when pytest sees this, it will execute the fruit_bowl fixture function and pass the object it returns into test_fruit_salad as the fruit_bowl argument."

Comment: Haha don't stress it -- it happens to us all! The good news is that you won't ever make this mistake again. Glad I could help =]